# Bufferedreader never null, while loop won't terminate

Tags: java, sockets, null, bufferedreader

I'm making a program where a client uses a proxy to ask a server to retrieve content from an URL, so for example, the client types in "http://www.google.ca", and they get the html code from that webpage. I got it to work once, but I want to it work multiple times. I tried using loops but they never terminate, bufferedreader never seems to = null for the Proxy or Client class (the Server class works fine though). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code

Client.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Client serv = new Client();
        serv.run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 7777); //connects to Proxy

        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream()); //output stream to Proxy

        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()); //input stream from Proxy
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //take input from keyboard

        //user types in an URL, outputs content of URL
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            ps.println(scanner.nextLine());
            String inputLine;
            while((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }
        sock.close();
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Proxy.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Proxy {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Proxy serv = new Proxy();
        serv.run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7777);
        Socket sock = ss.accept();

        //input and output streams to and from Client
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
        PrintStream psToClient = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());


        //input and output streams to and from Server
        Socket sck = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(sck.getOutputStream());
        InputStreamReader irFromServer = new InputStreamReader(sck.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader brFromServer = new BufferedReader(irFromServer);

        //passes message from Client to Server, passes URL content from Server back to Client
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String message = br.readLine();
            ps.println(message);
            System.out.println("Client wants me to tell Server he wants the content of: " + message);
            String inputLine;
            while((inputLine = brFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                psToClient.println(inputLine);
                //psToClient.flush();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }

        sock.close();
        ss.close();
        sck.close();
    }

}
```

Server.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server serv = new Server();
        serv.run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
        Socket sock = ss.accept();

        //input and output streams to and from Proxy
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
        PrintStream psToProxy = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

        //retrieves content from requested URL and sends back to Proxy
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String request = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Proxy told me Client wants the content from: " + request);

            //makes URL object using String value from Client
            URL url = new URL(request);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            //sends URL content back to Client, via Proxy
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                psToProxy.println(inputLine);
                //psToProxy.flush();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            System.out.println("FINISHED SENDING CONTENT");
            in.close();
        }

        sock.close();
        ss.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> bufferedreader never seems to = null

Your question is a little imprecise. What you mean is that `BufferedReader.readLine()` never returns `null.` That only happens when the peer closes the connection. If he never closes it, `readLine()` won't return null.

If you're writing an HTTP proxy you need to have a good look at RFC 2616, and specifically the requirements about the `Content-length` header, the `Connection: close` header, and chunked transfer encoding. Just reading the response stream to its end is in general not sufficient.